# G++ seems to be ignoring #ifdef for an #include

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

**Environment**
Ubuntu 16.04
G++ 5.3.1

I have a header file with the following intended to include a different .h file depending on platform:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 
#include "curses.h"
#else
#include <ncurses.h>
#endif
```

This works fine in windows but in Ubuntu I get errors about the curses.h file:

```
In file included from /usr/include/unctrl.h:54:0,
                 from /usr/include/curses.h:1694,
                 from headers/command_window.h:8,
                 from command_window.cpp:1:
headers/curses.h:900:19: error: macro "clear" passed 1 arguments, but takes just 0
int     clear(void);
```

This when compiling with:

```
g++  -g -lncurses -std=c++11  -Iheaders  -c -o command_window.o command_window.cpp
```

Why is headers/curses.h, which is the windows specific file for PDCurses being involved here at all?

Comment: Use [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2224357/440558) to learn how to dump all predefined macros. You can also stop after preprocessing to see the source as the compiler sees it.

Comment: _WIN32 does not appear to be in the list of defines using that old answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your version of g++, the `-I` option is not the correct way to add application-specific header files (those that shouldn't be found by `#include` in system headers) to the search path (this change surprised me as well).

Instead, you should use `-iquote headers`.

See this answer: [How to tell g++ compiler where to search for include files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15478111/103167) and this [official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/include/unctrl.h` contains this line:

`#include <curses.h>`

And since you've told the compiler to look in your `headers/` folder for header files with the `-Iheaders` flag , the compiler picks up `curses.h` in that folder.

So you need to drop the `-Iheaders` flag (and e.g. use #include "headers/header_name.h") or you need to rename your `headers/curses.h` to not collide with /usr/include/curses.h

Comment: This seems a bit off, your supposition is that it's using the system include syntax, but the `-I` option doesn't affect the search path for system headers.  In particular, *Any directories you specify with `-I` options before the `-I-` option are searched only for the case of `#include "file"`; they are not searched for `#include <file>`.*

Comment: Hmm, found the right version of the g++ docs and it looks like this was intentionally broken: *Please use `-iquote` instead for `-I` directories before the `-I-` and remove the `-I-` option. Any directories you specify with `-I` options before the `-I-` option are searched only for the case of `#include "file"`; they are not searched for `#include <file>`.
If additional directories are specified with `-I` options after the `-I-` option, these directories are searched for all `#include` directives. (Ordinarily all `-I` directories are used this way.) *

Comment: @BenVoigt The docs here, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html, states that directories added with `-I` are searched before any default directories (such as /usr/include) for #include files encased in `<brackets>` - and that matches my experience. The main difference with gcc between `"header"` and `<header>` is that "header" first relative to the file, and that `-I.` and `-I-` has special meanings.

Comment: There are two factors: the order, and whether `""` or `<>` is used in the `#include` to name the file.

Comment: @BenVoigt Directories added with `-I`  makes gcc search those before any system directories (such as /usr/include/)  in both the `""` and the `<>` case.

Comment: Thank you both. Both answers solved my problem but can accept only one!