# Eigen library problem: split_test_helper.h not found

Tags: c++, eigen, xilinx, eigen3

I am trying to compile my code that uses the Eigen library but I am having some difficulties. I have compiled and run my program in Visual Studio 2017 with no problems, but since I have to implement this code on some piece of hardware (namely Xilinx ZedBoard that runs Linux OS) I am trying to compile the same code in Xilinx SDK.

When trying to do that I get this error: fatal error: 
    split_test_helper.h: No such file or directory
I also get this error when building the project with Xilinx SDK -
    make: ***[eigen-eigen-323c052e1731/unsupported/test/subdir.mk:275:eigen- 
    eigen-323c052e1731/unsupported/test/BVH.o] Error 1

I am aware that split_test_helper.h file should be generated as it says in CMakeLists.txt but I guess it does not in the case of Xilinx SDK, but does in the case of compiling with Visual Studio.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Also I should maybe mention that I managed to compile and run the code from Linux terminal on a virtual box Linux OS from my computer using g++.

Comment: Have you added the directory, which has the `split_test_helper.h`, file as a compiler's directive (-I[include dir])? Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478005/how-to-tell-g-compiler-where-to-search-for-include-files

Comment: Eigen is header only, and does not require any configuration step, so all you have to do is tell where to find Eigen's header. The file `split_test_helper.h` is only referenced by the unit tests. Those are completely unrelated to your project. Here I see it tries to compile the BVH unit test... this does not make any sense. Please review your project setup.

Comment: Can you check the versions of cmake that you are using in Linux vs Xilinx? The script that generates the split_test_helper.h is at https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/f33ba4f6c409690b96cfe06fed367dc5292e9eb1/scripts/eigen_gen_split_test_help.cmake. It seems to be just writing some basic stuff not related to the underlying OS and you can probably get away with copying the file from the other system.